# How can I install debconf?

Tags: dpkg, debconf

I am trying to install debconf since it seems to be broken on my computer.

I ran the command:

```
apt-get -f install debconf
```

I got the following error message:

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I don't understand this error message and I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/info` Then retry & report back.

The -p switch says 'make parent folders if they don't exist', if they do nothing special happens but your folder is created.